# displaying and updating data of two tables from a grid (or table) in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need your guidance please for doing a unusual task which I am not getting how can be done. I have three database tables. CompanyName (it have Id and CompanyName columns)  and Agent (it has id and AgentName columns) and Rates (RowId,AgentCompanyName,AgentName and Date).

Requirment is to display data of Agent and Companies tables in one grid or table in a way that Companies will appear as columns and agents will appear as rows on top x-axis and agents will appear as rows (in one column) on y-exis. This is display just like a matrix and conjunction of each will have a textbox to get (agent's value for that company).

NOTE: update buttons can be on left side as a column or under table as a single button. There can be any no columns (compnayName) and any no of rows (agent names). On pressing Update these rates will be saved in Rates table.

How can I display such a page and how implement Update functionality?

[image]

Comment: If you're asking for a full coded solution, may be someone will respond. If you are asking about the approach, I would get multiple sets from the databas and make use of Data Relation to form the Column/Row permutations. As far as saving back is concerned that can be done if you know the row index and selected column.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what works best for you, you could create one stored procedure that accepts all of those fields and updates the tables, or you can execute an insert/update stored procedure for each table.